# I have a minimax algorithm but im not sure what to parse into position?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, minimax

I'm making a board game similar to mancala.
I based my algorithm off this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-hh51ncgDI

However I'm stuck with variable position and i think i still need to save the move. 
Its my first time doing AI and this project involved making AI for a unique Game. 
I think im doing this horribly wrong as i think minimax is supposed to be a tree diagram and i got no tree.

```
public class MiniMax 
{
    bool gameOver = false;
    public float minimax(position, int depth, float alpha, float beta, bool player1)
    {
        if (depth == 0 || GameOver())
        {
            float score = Utility();
        }


        if (player1)
        {
            float maxVal = float.MaxValue;
            foreach (var child in postition)
            {
                float eval = minimax(postition, depth - 1, alpha, beta, false);
                maxVal = Mathf.Max(maxVal, eval);
                alpha = Mathf.Max(alpha, eval);
                if (beta <= alpha)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return maxVal;
        }
        else
        {
            float minVal = float.MinValue;
            foreach (var child in postition)
            {
                float eval = minimax(postition, depth - 1, alpha, beta, true);
                minVal = Mathf.Max(minVal, eval);
                beta = Mathf.Max(beta, eval);
                if (beta <= alpha)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return minVal;
        }
    }

    bool GameOver()
    {
        return false;
    }

    float Utility()
    {
        //f(x) = -1(j.a + k.b) + l.c + m.d
        float a = GameManager.arr1[0].LightStones;
        float b = GameManager.arr2[0].DarkStones;
        float c = GameManager.arr1[7].LightStones;
        float d = GameManager.arr2[7].DarkStones;

        float j;
        if(a > c)
        {
            j = 1.5f;
        }
        else
        {
            j = 1;
        }

        float k;
        if (b > d)
        {
            k = 1.5f;
        }
        else
        {
            k = 1;
        }

        float l;
        if (c > a)
        {
            l = 1.5f;
        }
        else
        {
            l = 1;
        }

        float m;
        if (d > b)
        {
            m = 1.5f;
        }
        else
        {
            m = 1;
        }

        return (-1*((j*a) + (k*b))) + (l*c) + (m*d);
    }

}
```

Comment: You are searching the hypothetical game tree, that's where the tree comes in. Though you could if you wanted to, you usually do not need to store the tree that you traverse, it's only the score that is interesting, and then, for the top level only, the move that leads to the best score.

Comment: yeah that would be the tree of all possible moves from a certain position (and then in the next depth level all moves starting from that new position  ... and so on) so probably something like `public class PositionTree { public int x; public int y; public PositionTree[] nextPositions; }` where every different game piece has a different implementation of how to get and fill in the `nextPositions` .. e.g. pawn: if not at final row then either one field in front, if not moved yet either one or two fields in front, or one diagonal field in front if there is an opponent.

Comment: @derHugo in my case i have to create a replica of the board and alter it as if a move took place in order to calculate the outcome. Wow sounds cool I'm going to jump in i have a function that calculate next move so i think i will use that already and avoid the Position tree but I see How that would be more beneficial for a game like chess.

Comment: Thanks to the both of you!